# Dynamic header and footer liferay

Tags: dynamic, header, liferay, footer

I am searching the way to use a jsp file in the web content, because i do a dynamic load of dates to show on a navigation bar. Also, I want set this web content as header and footer.

Actually my page is this, http://pachonweb.no-ip.org.

I want to replace the Liferay's header by portlet's page shown in below

Thank for your help.

Comment: you can include the portlet in the theme by modifying your theme's `portal_normal.vm`, here is a [blog](http://www.liferay.com/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/embedding-portlets-in-themes-on-liferay) about it. See if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for adding web content in header and footer u need to call web content in theme.
you can refer
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/24879333

Comment: Thanks for everything, I was finally able to include the portlet on the theme, now what fails me is the superposition of divs, for example, the navigation bar to be in another portlet, when displaying the elements, not shown well as some has been below the other portlet, and tried with z-index, but does not work, any ideas?